# python script to slice filenames to certain length

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python language, trying to write a script that can slice the last characters of filenames to a specific length.
It worked, but for some reason, it denied to proceed and the loop unexpectedly broke giving an error message that the file doesn't exist.
error message: "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:"
Here is my script, please tell me what is wrong!!!

```py
import os
#define a function to trim latest characters to a specefic length"""
def renamer(folderpath, newlength):
    while True:
        for filename in os.listdir(folderpath):
            root = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
            exten = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
            while len(root) >= newlength:
                os.rename(folderpath + '\\' + root + exten, folderpath + '\\' + root[:-1] + exten)
            continue
        if len(root) <= newlength:
            break
```

Comment: what error message did you get? also use `os.path.join()` to join paths instead of using string addition.

Comment: error message:FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:

Comment: Please edit the question and include the error message in question

Answer (score 0):

I do not like the way you are doing the task, but for solving your problem I am stating the mistake you are doing.

You changed the file from root='Name' to root='Nam' but did not update the value of root. So the next time the loop runs, it again looks for a file 'name' which obviously does not exist, because you renamed it to 'nam'.

So update the value of root also and you will be good to go.

But again, I should mention that you should solve it in some other way.

Comment: How to do make the loop update the value of "root"? thank you

Comment: After os.rename() call, just do root = root[:-1]

Comment: Amazing, it worked, thank you very much. If you have better solution, would you please share it

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems here :

- It's a good idea to use `os.path.join` for joining the folder and file name, so that it works on all systems without having to change the code (Eg. - *nix OSes that use `/` instead of `\` as the seperator), instead of concatenating the `\\` directly
- Like @Illrnr said, the problem is that after the first rename (eg. `abcdefgh.png` to `abcdefg.png`), the code will continue looking for the old filename (`abcdefgh.png`) and this raises the error.
- Using a while loop to keep shortening it one character at a time is complicating your logic, and will increase the runtime of your code a lot too with so many calls to `rename` - you can shorten it to required length in one go without all those loops and tracking length etc etc...

Try this and see if you understand the code:

```py
import os

def renamer(folderpath, newlength):
    for filename in os.listdir(folderpath):
        root, exten = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if len(root)>newlength:
            oldname = os.path.join(folderpath, root+exten)
            newname = os.path.join(folderpath, root[:newlength]+exten)
            os.rename(oldname, newname)
            print(f"Shortened {oldname} to {newname}")
```

Comment: yes, that is very good one, I appreciate your help.